# XmlSerializer ShouldSerialize* doesn't work for base type property

Tags: .net, serialization, xml-serialization

If I define ShouldSerialize* for current type property, it works. But it doesn't work if I specify base type property. The same for *Specified

```
 [XmlInclude(typeof(SingleEventGroup))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(MultipleEventsGroup))]
    public abstract class EventsGroup
    {
        public List<int> EventsIds { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

 public class SingleEventGroup : EventsGroup
    {
        public bool ShouldSerializeName()
        {
            return false; //it is still serialized
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XmlSerializer looks for the method on the .DeclaringType of your member `Name`, not on the .ReflectedType. This is why it doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like it does work if you implement `ShouldSerializeName` in the base type as virtual then override in the inherited types.

Comment: any work around... if you dont have access to the base class?